# crawling through Selenium Webdriver, (When using yield), an error occurs

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, yield

:)

I'm crawling through Selenium Webdriver.
If not use yield, it works fine, but
When using yield, the following error occurs.
What should I do?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 49, in process_spider_input
    return scrape_func(response, request, spider)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\scraper.py", line 146, in call_spider
    dfd.addCallbacks(request.callback or spider.parse, request.errback)
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 303, in addCallbacks
    assert callable(callback)
```

this is code here :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('arrays.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

class LgSpider(Spider):
    name = 'lg'
    allowed_domains = ['naturecollection.co.kr/product/list.jsp?cate_seq=4']


    def start_requests(self):
        reader = csv.reader(open('urls1.csv'))

        for row in reader:
            url = row[0]
            # self.parse_detail(url)
            yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_detail(url))


    def parse_detail(self, url):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('/webdrivers/chromedriver')
        self.driver.get(url)
        sleep(10)

        sel = Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)
        # sleep(2)
        # self.logger.info('Sleeping for 2 seconds.')
        response = url
        sub_kor = sel.xpath('//meta[@property="og:title"]/@content').extract()
        sub_en = sel.xpath('//*[@class="section fr"]//*[@class="subTit"]/text()').extract()
        highlight_1 = sel.xpath('//meta[@property="og:description"]/@content').extract()
        main = sel.xpath('//meta[@property="og:image"]/@content').extract()
        category_1 = sel.xpath('//*[@id="locationArea"]/div/a/text()').extract()
        category_2 = sel.xpath('//*[@id="locationArea"]/strong/text()').extract()
        # table = sel.xpath('//*[@id="specInfoLayer"]//td').extract()
        noop_originpirce = sel.xpath('//*[@class="section fr"]//*[@class="realCost"]/text()').extract()
        noop_real_price = sel.xpath('//*[@class="section fr"]//span[@class="cost"]/text()').extract()
        real_price = sel.xpath('//*[@class="colorChip optionList"]//input[@name="cost"]/@value').extract()
        stock_no = sel.xpath('//*[@class="colorChip optionList"]//*[contains(@id, "stock")]/@value').extract()
        options = sel.xpath('//*[@class="colorChip optionList"]//@title').extract()
        brand = sel.xpath('//span[@class="brand"]/text()').extract_first()
        rating = sel.xpath('//*[@class="starArea"]/span/text()').extract()
        description = sel.xpath('//*[@id="proExplain"]//p').extract()
        image_urls = sel.xpath('//*[@class="thumList"]/li/a/img/@src').extract()
        volume = sel.xpath('//*[@id="specInfoLayer"]//tbody/tr[1]/td/text()').extract()
        skin_type = sel.xpath('//*[@id="specInfoLayer"]//tbody/tr[2]').extract()
        expire_date = sel.xpath('//*[@id="specInfoLayer"]//tbody/tr[3]').extract()
        method = sel.xpath('//*[@id="specInfoLayer"]//tbody/tr[4]').extract()
        manufature = sel.xpath('//*[@id="specInfoLayer"]//tbody/tr[5]').extract()
        ingridient = sel.xpath('//*[@id="specInfoLayer"]//tbody/tr[6]').extract()



        for idx, option in enumerate(options):

            yield  {'Option': options[idx],
                   # 'A': a,
                   'Volume': volume,
                   'Skin_type': skin_type,
                   'Expire_date': expire_date,
                   'Method': method,
                   'Manufature': manufature,
                   'Url': url,
                   'Sub_kor': sub_kor,
                   'Sub_en': sub_en,
                   'Highlight': highlight_1,
                   'Noop_Origin_price': noop_originpirce,
                   'Noop_real_price': noop_real_price,
                   'Real_price': real_price[idx],
                   'Category_1': category_1,
                   'Category_2': category_2,
                   # 'Category_3': category_3,
                   # 'Category_4': category_4,
                   'Stock_no': stock_no,
                   'Description': description,
                   'Rating': rating,
                   'Ingridient': ingridient,
                   'Brand': brand,
                   # 'Ingridient_text': ingridient_text,
                   'Image_urls': image_urls,
                   # 'Table_dts': table_dts,
                   # 'Table_dds': table_dds,
                   # 'Options': options[idx],
                   # 'Brand': brand,
                   # 'Table' : table,
                   # 'Buyer_no': buyer_no,
                   # 'Repurchase' : repurchase,
                   'Main': main
                   }




    def close(self, reason):
        # pass
        csv_file = max(glob.iglob('*.csv'), key=os.path.getctime)

        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active

        with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                # row = row.encode('utf-8')
                try:
                    ws.append(row)
                except:
                    continue

        wb.save(csv_file.replace('.csv', '') + '.xlsx')enter code here
```

thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that when you're using `yield` you need to iterate through the generator that youv'e created. So your `generator` would be `start_requests`, which is yielding each row from your reader.

So you will need to store your generator then iterate over it. See the description of python `yield` - [What does the "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that something is not right with your callback

You should to delete the 2º url call in your callback, your code will be like this

```
 yield Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_detail)
```

Additionally I will use a response object instead of a selector.

Your code will be like this:

```
def parse_detail(self,response)
   sub_kor = response.xpath('//meta....')
```